# How to count character length in reg-ex

Tags: jquery

How to count character length in reg-ex now i am using

```
function CheckForAlphaRegName(theObj) {
if (theObj.value.match(/[^a-zA-Z-\'\s]+/)) {
    theObj.value = theObj.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z-\'\s]+/g, "");
}
if (theObj.value.match(/[-\'\s]+/).length > 1) {
    theObj.value.match(/[-\'\s]+/g, "");
}
```

Comment: `theObj.value.match(/[-\'\s]+/)[1].length`

Comment: That code is extremely awkward. You don't need the first `if` condition at all (it's redundant), and although I see what the second one is doing, I can't imagine why you'd want to. What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

For this particular example that you have, you want to make sure that the string you are looking for matches you Regexp or not. So just check if it is not null by trying the following code

```
if (theObj.value.match(/[-\'\s]+/)) {
    theObj.value.match(/[-\'\s]+/g, "");
}
```

If theObj.value.match(/[-\'\s]+/) returns **'null'** then it indicates that there is no match. Hope it helps.